# SQL : JOIN from two different servers using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here is the problem:
Using the ASP.NET platform, I have two SQL tables on two different servers (SQL 2016 and SQL 2005), and I want to return a JSON object on a C# code behind.

Table 1 on server A (SQL 2005) contains all information on all tablets that can be checked out (the bulk of the data)

All I need from Table 2 on server B (SQL 2016) is the Barcode, and the boolean field that tells me if the tablet has been checked out.

Complicating matters is that I am using Server side paging, mainly on the SQL 2005 side. So at some point, this will be part of the Server B data pull:

`SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE) AS NUMBER,
                    .....
               ) AS TBL
WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE`

The link between the two tables is the Barcode.

Thus:

`Table 1 (Server A)
| BARCODE | LAH | DI | DOO | DAH |
|---------|-----|----|-----|-----|
| 0000001 | foo | 1  |  A  |  No |
| 000001A | bar | 1  |  A  | Yes |
| 0000002 | mit | 2  |  S  | Yes |
| 0000003 | zva | 1  |  A  | Yes |
.
.
.`

`Table 2 (Server B)
| BARCODE | CheckOut | Beep | BeepBeep |
|---------|----------|------|----------|
| 0000001 |   True   |  11  | 3/2/2017 |
| 0000002 |  False   |  12  | 3/1/2017 |
| 0000003 |   True   |  14  | 3/7/2017 |
.
.
.`

What I want returned is BARCODE, LAH and DOO from table 1 (Server A) and CheckOut from table 2 (Server B), with a join at BARCODE, where CheckOut is equal to 'True'.

I have two ideas about the problem: 
One was to create a temporary table on one of the servers, add the CheckOut column, and form the JSON object that way. It's a quick and dirty solution. After a while, I felt this was becoming wasteful.

The second idea is to use the [LIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) Class in C#. Because I am returning a LIST object, surely there is a way to add the CheckOut column to LIST.

Does the community have ideas about this?

Comment: This is the difficult part: the CheckOut column must be filterable and sortable.

Comment: LIST will not work in this situation. I will need to build some sort of view on the SQL 2005 server, import the column from SQL 2016. Sort and filter and use paging functions using that view.

Comment: ...or i can create a server object and make life easier on myself!

Answer (score 0):

That ended up being the answer:

On Server A, create a Linked Server object to Server B. Then, make only one SELECT statement. In its most general form:

`SELECT Table1.BARCODE, Table1.LAH, Table1.DAH, r.CheckOut
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
[Server B].database.dbo.Table2 AS r ON Table1.BARCODE = r.BARCODE
WHERE r.CheckOut = 'True'`